# Nuxtjs How to manage state for two diferent sources of data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxtjs, using Vuex inside Nuxtjs, how can i get data from **two** diferent data sources ?

I have a **courses** table and **course categories** table.

The courses **i already can** retrieve and show, the course categories **i just could not** until this moment.

My structure is :

At **stores** directory i have these files :

- index.js
- courses.js
- courseCategories (only change the api call and the name of the )

---

At **pages** directory i have these files:

- index.vue
- courses.vue

At pages/index.vue:

```
async fetch({store}){
    await store.dispatch('courses/fetchAllCourses')
    await store.dispatch('coursesCategories/fetchAllCoursesCategories')
  }
```

At pages/courses.vue i have the computed properties:

```
courses(){
    return this.$store.state.courses.all
},
coursesCategories(){
    return this.$store.state.coursesCategories.all
},
```

At stores/courses.js i have this code :

```
export const state = () => ({
    all : []    
})

export const actions = {
   async fetchAllCourses({commit}) {
        let courses = await this.$axios.$get('/courses/')
        commit('setCourses', courses)
   }
}

export const mutations  = {
    setCourses(state, courses) {
        state.all = courses
    }
}
```

For categories i just change the api call to `courseCategories` and rename the variable

How can i get the course categories data ? what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I can't see anything particularly wrong with what you are doing. If you are getting courses and your api call to courseCategories is correct it should work. You should consider using getters to return the store data but you could also use [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) which does that for you. I can only think you've got an error for "trying to mutate state outside a mutation handler" or whatever it says. Have you checked console errors.

Comment: after some debugging at data property i set again courses:this.$store.state.coursesCategories.all and it works

Comment: @Andrew1325 Thank´s for the advice on mapState